# Android Background Location Service not returning new locations

Tags: android, location

I am new to the Android Development environment.  I would like to have a service that is able to run in the background to provide me location updates when the phone moves at say 30 meters.  I can get the last location (I display it on a web view) but do not get any new updates as I move the phone.
    I have placed this line in my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


    <!-- for google play services -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <service android:name="LocationBackgroundService"></service>
```

Here is the code.  What am I missing?  Thank you in advance for your help.

**MainActivity onCreate**:

```
    boolean connected = myLocationManager.servicesConnected();
    // services connected is the same code as   http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html
    // load my web page ….
```

Because I want my web page loaded first so I can draw on its map, I do not connect to the google play services until 
**onPageFinished** in my web view client:

```
    myLocationManager.connectToGoogleLocationServices();
```

which looks like:

```
    this.locationClient = new LocationClient(MainActivity.this, this, this);
    this.locationClient.connect();
```

Once I do the connect, the  call back for the connection is invoked.
This is where I create my background service and get it started through using a pending intent as follows in the **onConnected** callback:

```
    locationHandler = new LocationBackgroundService();
    this.myPendingIntent = locationHandler.startHandler(MainActivity.this, locationClient);
    // get current location
Location location = locationClient.getLastLocation();
if (location != null)
{
        locationHandler.storeLastLocation(location) ;
        // at this point we know the web page is up to draw on

}

this.request = LocationRequest.create();
this.request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
this.request.setInterval(2 * 1000);
this.request.setSmallestDisplacement(distanceFilter);

// start monitoring locations in the background
this.locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, this.myPendingIntent);
```

I do see the “last location” appear on my web page in its proper location.  But that is it – no more.

Here is the code for the LocationBackgroundService service :

```
    public class LocationBackgroundService extends IntentService
    {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     */
     public LocationBackgroundService()
     {
        super("LocationReceiverHandler");

        logger.warning("LocationReceiverHandler constructed!");
     }

     /**
      * method gets the location changes
      */
     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
     {
        logger.info("in onHandleIntent in thread " + Thread.class.getName());

        Location location =                       intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if (location != null)
        {
            onLocationChanged(location) ;
            //notifyMainActivity(location);
        }
        else
        {
            MainActivity.getJavaScript().showMessageOnWebPage("No LOCATION");
        }

    public PendingIntent startHandler(Context myAppContext, LocationClient locationClient)
     {

        this.myAppContext = myAppContext;
        logger.warning("in startHandler " + Thread.class.getName());
        Intent mIntentService = new Intent(myAppContext, this.getClass());
        // Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a service, like calling Context.startService().
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(myAppContext, 1, mIntentService,         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
     }

     public void storeLastLocation (Location location )
     {
        this.lastLocation = location ;


        String newLocaionJSonString = createJSONLocationString(location);
        MainActivity.getJavaScript().drawMeOnWebScreen(newLocaionJSonString);
     }

     public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
     {

        if (location != null)
            {
            logger.warning("onLocationChanged " + location);
            boolean send = isFarEnoughLocationFromNew(location, this.distanceFilter);
            //if (send)
            {
            String newLocaionJSonString = createJSONLocationString(location);
            MainActivity.getJavaScript().drawMeOnWebScreen(newLocaionJSonString);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.severe("onLocationChanged return null location");
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to use `IntentService` for that because once the onHandleIntent finishes the service stops itself. so you wont get callback. you need to use the regular `Service` to keep getting location updates.

It would probably be better if you do everything in your MainActivity

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  The interesting part is that I don't even get into the intent service "once."  shouldn't I at least get in once?

Comment: I have personally never used `requestLocationUpdates` with PendingIntent so I dont really know and dont want to send you in the wrong direction but I do know using IntentService is not going to work, just move everything to your main activity

Comment: The reason I did not put everything into my main activity is that I want the service to run when the activity is not visible, namely when a phone call comes in or the user moves to another app.  Thank you for letting me know about the intent service firing once.

Comment: Yeah switch everything over to a regular service then go from there. That will run like you want

Comment: How do I make LocationBackgroundService receive changed locations?  In other words, what call back should it implement - since onHandleIntent  is no longer correct?  Thank you!